# Gradle not recognizing Cumulocity Microservice SDK package

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle, cumulocity

I managed to deploy a standalone *microservice* instance into Cumulocity platform according to [documentation](http://cumulocity.com/guides/rest/microservice-development/).
After deploying microservice to the platform, I am able to subscribe and make REST calls to the service, so everything works as expected.
**Cumulocity Microservice SDK** is based on Maven, therefore I have correct *pom.xml* specified.

The problem that I encounter is that I also have Gradle enabled in the project and CI setup based on Gradle in Gitlab and although everything works as should in Maven, the Microservice SDK package is not recognized by Gradle and I can't find a way to make it work. For example specific Microservice annotations that come up with the SDK are not recognized:

```
error: cannot find symbol @MicroserviceApplication
```

My current Maven specification includes:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java</groupId>
      <artifactId>microservice-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${c8y.version}</version>
      <configuration>
          ...
      </configuration>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              ...
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```

My current Gradle specification includes:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java:java-client:8.13.0'
}
```

I could rewrite CI specification to use only Maven but I was wondering, is there any way to make Gradle recognize Cumulocity Microservice SDK plugin from Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java-clients is not what you need. Try 'com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java:microservice-autoconfigure:8.13.0'. That's where the @MicroserviceApplication annotation should be.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked and Gradle build is passing. The only problem now is that my tests are not passing: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`. Will have to dig deeper but have no clue how to solve it.